C++ Filesystem Not Working in VSCode with g++ 13.2: No Output or Errors
Im trying to write an app to count the number of lines, characters etc. in a directory, in order to do that i need to get the path and for that i was plannning on using the c++ filesystem, sadly it is not working and to make it worse its not throwing any errors the code just doesnt yield any output. I dont know if it matters but im using vscode and g++ 13.2.
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main(){
    std::filesystem::path path = std::filesystem::current_path();
    std::cout << "Current path: " << path << std::endl;
}

I tried printing the path, creating a file or a directory using the path and nothing works.

In what window or tab do you look? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build and run output.

At a guess you're using windows and have an incompatible libstdc++ dll somewhere on your path, alternatively you've got no libstdc++ dll on your path. A debugger would be able to tell you more

FWIW I cannot reproduce on VisualStudio (and MSVC). When I run you code I get the valid current folder.

thanks @AlanBirtles, i reinstaled my mingw and everythin works fine, helped a lot
